# white list client IP address, but still get 403 forbidden error for phpMyAdmin in CentOS

Tags: phpmyadmin, centos, devops

I have white list client IP address in /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf as below,

```
#Apache 2.4
<RequireAny>
   Require ip 127.0.0.1
   Require ip <ip address> # Added my client(windows system ip)
   Require ip ::1
</RequireAny>
...
...
...
#Apache 2.4
<RequireAny>
   Require ip 127.0.0.1
   **Require ip <ip address> # Added my client(windows system ip)**
   Require ip ::1
</RequireAny>
```

then I restarted the httpd service, but still I get 403 Forbidden error when I open the link in browser /phpMyAdmin

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access/phpMyAdmin on this server.

If anyone have faced similar issue or you have solution for this please post here.

Thanks,
Girish LC

Comment: Have you try to add all IPs on one line?

Comment: @RomeoNinov, I found the root cause for this issue.

Comment: Hi Friends, I have found the RC for this issue, problem is I had taken a backup of the file /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf in the same folder as /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf.bk, and this backup configuration file was affecting the client. After moving the backup file to other folder (in my case I moved to /tmp) I'm able to run the phpMyAdmin in the browser.